# It is showing connected but insert statement is not working. error parameter count mismatch

Tags: mysql, qt

```
1.int main(int argc, char *argv[])
2.{
3.    QApplication a(argc, argv);
4.    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
5.    db.setHostName("localhost");
6.    db.setDatabaseName("test");
7.    db.setUserName("root");
8.    db.setPassword("12345678");
9.    if (!db.open())
10.    {
11.        qDebug()<< "Not Conn";
12.        return false;
13.    }
14.    else
15.    {
16.        qDebug()<<"connected";
17.        QSqlQuery qry;
18.        qry.prepare("insert into test.inter(id,cname)     
19.                     values(:id,:cname)");//id int, cname varchar(19)
20.        qry.bindValue(0,2);
21.        qry.bindValue(1,"far");
22.        if(qry.exec())
23.        {
24.            qDebug()<<"Inserted";
25.        }
26.        else
27.        {
28.            qDebug()<<qry.lastError().text();
29.            qDebug()<<qry.result();
30.            qDebug()<<qry.executedQuery();
31.        }
32.   }
33. }
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `mysql` but are using QSQLITE instead of QMYSQL driver. Is this a typo?

Comment: actually, I coudnot get anyfile like mysql.dll in C:\Qt\5.0.2\mingw47_32\plugins\sqldrivers. but sqlite.dll and qsqlodbc.dll are avail

Comment: Weird, i don't know about 5.0.2 but in 5.6 the mysql driver is located on `C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\mingw49_32\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll`. Maybe your installation is broken. If you keep using `QSQLITE` then `setHostName`, `setUserName` and `setPassword` are gonna be ignored and it will create a empty database file (it won't have any tables so the parameter count mismatch will show).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your bindValues with:

```
$sth->bindValue(':id', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':cname', "far", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or...

Replace line 19 with:

```
values(?, ?)");
```

So try replacing lines 20 - 21 with:

```
qry.bindValue(":id:",2);
qry.bindValue(":cname","far");
```

Comment: qry.prepare("insert into test.inter(id,cname) values(?,?)");//changed 19 but same

Comment: does your code now look like:
`QSqlQuery qry;`
`qry.prepare("insert into test.inter(id,cname) values(?, ?)");`
`qry.bindValue(0,2);`
`qry.bindValue(1,"far");`

Comment: "No query Unable to fetch row" 
0x13dc5ca0 
"insert into test.inter(id,cname) values(?,?)"

Comment: Check your table name (you may not require the "test.") and your column names.

Comment: qry.bindValue(0,2); //" Parameter count mismatch"                                    qry.bindValue(":id",2);//"No query Unable to fetch row"

Comment: I checked column name.

Comment: Your last comment still seems to have bindValues with ":id" in it. I have made an edit to my original answer with some drop-in code. Try that.

Comment: still same error. Also I like to say if use qry.bindValue(0,2); //error return" Parameter count mismatch".   But if use qry.bindValue(":id",2);//than error return   "No query Unable to fetch row".

Comment: yes I did,  qry.prepare("insert into inter(id,cname) values (?, ?)");
        qry.bindValue(":id",2);
        qry.bindValue(":cname","far");      now getting error "No query Unable to fetch row" . I checked table inter and column also. what should i do now_

Answer (score 0):

Remove the database name from the prepared statement. Isn't needed since you are specifying when calling `setDatabaseName`. (the database name in the query is what causes the misleading error). Leave the insert as:

`qry.prepare("insert into inter(id,cname) values(:id,:cname)");`

Comment: ya, I did so and still getting like,                                                                    " Parameter count mismatch" 
0x180e5a30 
"insert into inter(id,cname) values (?, ?)"